# Preview access not operating

Tags: macbook-pro

My computer won't allow me to access to the preview function. This has automatically opened documents in the past. I gat a fault 1712.

Comment: Please define the "preview function"

Answer (score 1):

Pure guess…

- Open `~/Library/QuickLook`
- Open `Library/QuickLook`
- Remove all plugins
- Test
- Replace one at a time until you find the crasher.
- See if there is a newer version.